# What is Generative Training?

Tags: machine-learning, estimation, terminology

I know that the difference between **generative** and **discriminative** **classifiers** is that the generative ones directly model the distribution of the observed data while the discriminative ones do not.

But then I come across the term ***discriminative training*** in which there are **Minimum Classification Error(MCE)** and **Maximum Mutual Information(MMI)** estimation. These two methods seems to estimate the parameters for the generative classifiers. It confuses me where the ***discriminative*** comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Generative training is to $\hat M$(learned model) close to the overall joint distribution $P^{*}(Y,X)$ while discriminative training is to get $\hat P(Y|X)$ to be close to $P^{*}(Y|X)$. And the discriminative training is usually performed in the context of undirected models.